# How to pass variable inside find element method in Selenium , Python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I need to do some changes in below line :

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("[href='/new/ank/abgh/add/']")
```

Now I have create a string variable lStr and assign href value to it:

```
lStr="/new/ank/abgh/add/"
```

Now I want to know how to replace `/new/ank/abgh/add/` with variable lStr  in above selenium command. I tried like below :

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("[href='{lStr}']")
```

but it is not working, I am new to python so do know how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use plus sign to concatenate them.

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("[href='" + lStr + "']")
#browser.find_element_by_css_selector("[href='"+ str(lStr) + "']")
```

Comment: In below line: browser.find_element_by_css_selector("[href='/new/ank/abgh/add/']")